# Php Xpath query returning "Array"

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

ive got my xml file and also heres my php script

```
 $db  =  simplexml_load_file("BIN/videos.xml");

$id = $_GET['id'];

$tq = "//video['@id=" . $id . "']/title[0]";
$dq = "//video['@id=" . $id . "']/description[1]";
$eq = "//video['@id=" . $id . "']/embed[2]";

$title  = $db->xpath($tq);

$description = $db->xpath($dq);

$embed  = $db->xpath($eq); 

include("design/lyt.php");

echo $embed . '<br>
<h1>' . $title . '</h1>
<p>' . $description . '</p>';

?>
```

Its supposed to display "Test" for them all! but it says "Array"

Comment: Can you post the XML, or at least a sample?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP needs to [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` returns an `array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the elements of the `array` returned from `xpath`...

**PHP >= 5.4:**

```
$title  = $db->xpath($tq)[0];
```

**PHP < 5.4:**

Update PHP :-)

or

```
list($title,)  = $db->xpath($tq);
```

or

```
$title  = $db->xpath($tq);
$title = $title[0];
```