# php xpath returns node value as Array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath

Im using xpath to get values for a cms page,

```
video?id=blahblah
```

My PHP Xpath Code is

```
<?php
$db = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$title = $db->xpath("//video[@id=$id]/title");
```

Im doing this for all values, below is my xml code

```
<data>
<video id="1">
<title>Test</title>
</video>
```

I want the title heading to say Test but it says array instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061514/php-xpath-query-returning-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath queries return a sequence of result nodes, not a single one. SimpleXML returns this as an array of SimpleXMLElements (which have reasonable `__toString` implementations, so you can directly output them in string context).

So if you're sure you will only have a single result, just pick the first item of the array:

```
$title = $db->xpath("//video[@id=$id]/title")[0];
```